# Is this a good example of open recursion?

Tags: recursion

I understand *open recursion* as the process of a method on a class calling another method on a class using a keyword such as `this`, but whereby the method call may actually be bound to a sub class at run time.

Is this a fair demonstration of open recursion?

```
class Sup {
    go() {
        alert('sup');
    }

    callGo() {
        this.go();
    }
}

class Sub extends Sup {
    go() {
        alert('sub');
    }
}

var sub = new Sub();
sub.callGo();
```

Comment: ...I don't see any recursion here at all of any sort...

Comment: [Open Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_(computer_programming)#Open_recursion) != [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Comment: @Ampt But open recursion still is still recursion. Simply delegating to another method, whether it may be overriden or not, is neither open recursion nor regular recursion.

Comment: @delnan - can you explain in an answer? I didn't think open recursion required a traditional recursive call to the same methods - just to other methods via `this` or `self` and that may not be defined on the same class, but potentially on a sub class.

Comment: This is a very good article on teaching the concept of open recursion (I have been unable to find anything else that is good): http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2013/08/26/what-is-open-recursion/

Comment: @ThomasEding Excellent article.  Explains the concept well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a good example of open recursion.

> **Open recursion.** Another handy feature offered by most languages with objects and classes is the ability for one method body to invoke another method of the same object via a special variable called `self` or, in some langauges, `this`. The special behavior of `self` is that it is *late-bound*, allowing a method defined in one class to invoke another method that is defined later, in some subclass of the first.
>
> -- Types and Programming Languages, Benjamin C. Pierce, 2002, MIT Press, pg 227.

In the example, the method `Sup.callGo` calls the method `go` defined in the subclass. This is open recursion according to Pierce's definition. The methods don't need to have the same name.

Comment: Hi @tom thanks for the answer - this is interesting because that was my understanding of open recursion when I originally asked. The super class calls itself, but this call can be dispatched to the sub-classes implementation. I now stand re-corrected!

Answer (score 5):

No, in this case `Sub` will simply override `Sup.go()` and so only `Sub.go()` is executed.

Open recursion is when a method in a class can call itself (i.e. its own signature) which is recursion, but due to dynamic dispatch (can) actually call a subclass, which is open recursion:

```java
class A {
    protected int counter = 1;
    public void loop() {
        System.out.println("Looping " + counter + " times");
        counter++;
        this.loop();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void loop() {
        if(counter == 1) {
             super.loop();
        }
    }
}
```

Now `new A().loop()` will loop indefinitly<sup>*</sup>, but `new B().loop()` will terminate.

<sup>*</sup> It will actually cause a stack overflow unless you have an inifinite stack or tail-call optimization

Comment: I don't think I understand you example. In your example, `new A().loop()` will continually call the loop method on `A`. `new b().loop()` will call the loop method once on `B`. There is no point in here where the call would be dispatched to a super or sub class?

Comment: Repro'd in C#. +1 Interesting!

Comment: @SteveFenton On B, `super.loop()` calls the method on A.  Then inside A, `this.loop()` calls the method on B because it is an instance of B, not A.  On the instance of A, `this.loop()` calls itself forever.  (Or at least, that was what was intended.  dtech, you forgot to make B a subclass of A)

Comment: Yes - brilliant, I missed the super call. So the flow would be `b.loop... if(counter==1)... super.loop->a.loop... Sysoutprint... counter++... this.loop->b.loop...`

Comment: @Izkata Oops, fixed

Comment: Ah this is a great explanation! As someone familiar with recursion from playing in FP, *this* fits in my head as a form of recursion where the description in the question has nothing in the slightest to do with it.

Comment: Please cite your definition of open recursion. It doesn't match the one in Types and Programming Languages by Benjamin Pierce (see my answer).